# How do I open the segment index of my segment controller from app delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appdelegate, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to display the "Menu View Controller" when a local notification was opened. I use a segment control in the "Menu View Controller", which should be set to selectedSegmentIndex = 0, when the view was opened through local notifications. I am able to open the View Controller but I do not know how to address the segment Control from app delegate?
This is the code I use:

```
 // open the menu view controller when notification is pressed

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first
        if let sceneDelegate = scene?.delegate as? SceneDelegate {  
            if let tabController = sceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                  tabController.selectedIndex = 0 // index for menu view conntroller
            }
        }

        // set selected index of the segment control equal to zero


        completionHandler()

    }
```

This is how my storyboard looks:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not tried your answer , but try this

steps :

initially you need to get the viewcontrollers of tabbarcontroller, like this

```
 if  let getMenuVC = tabController.viewControllers.first, let getMenu = getMenuVC as? yourMenuController{
  }
```

then you need to get the current class as your menuviewcontroller as like

```
  if let getMenu = getMenuVC as? yourMenuController{
  }
```

finally you need to upadte the segment selected index of your current class as like

```
   if let getMenu = getMenuVC as? yourMenuController{
         getMenu.yourSegmentedControlName.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
getMenu.yourSegmentedControlName.sendActions(for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
      }
```

final code as :

```
 if let tabController = sceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                  tabController.selectedIndex = 0 // index for menu view conntroller
             if  let getMenuVC = tabController.viewControllers?.first, let getMenu = getMenuVC as? yourMenuController{
         getMenu.yourSegmentedControlName.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
getMenu.yourSegmentedControlName.sendActions(for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
      }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works!!! Just had to add a question mark behind the 'viewControllers' in line 3.